# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable shape drawing

Tags: python

Hey everyone I am trying to learn Python and am currently trying to write a program to draw different shapes. Everything is working except the part where I define drawShapes at the end I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seanrose/Desktop/Homework 4-1.py", line 126, in <module>
    drawShapes(nick, allshapes[i])
  File "/Users/seanrose/Desktop/Homework 4-1.py", line 121, in drawShapes
    for i in (numberofside):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKUip.png
sorry here is an image to the code

or here is the part that isnt working 
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    nick = turtle.Turtle()
    nick.color(penco)
    nick.pensize(penwid)
    wn.bgcolor(bcco)

```
def drawShapes(t, typeofshape):
totaldegrees = typeofshape[0]
numberofside = typeofshape[1]
lengthofsides = typeofshape[2]
whatkindofshape = typeofshape[3]
t.write(whatkindofshape)
for i in (numberofside):
    t.forward(lengthofsides)
    t.left(totaldegrees/numberofside)

for i in range(len(allshapes)):
drawShapes(nick, allshapes[i])
```

Comment: Nobody can see the screenshots except you.  Please paste the relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Your problem is inside of `drawShape()`, not in the code you included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, you seem to have this code:

```
for i in (numberofside):
```

Since `numberofside` is an integer, this will not work.  If you want to iterate over the numbers from 0 to `numberofside`, try this.

```
for i in range(numberofside):
```